# Pandas Group then Shift Column and keep last row

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I want to group column **idx** then shift column **val** and keep the last row with **idx**.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'idx':['a','a','b','b'],
                   'val':['a1','a2','b1','b2']})

df

   idx  val
0   a   a1
1   a   a2
2   b   b1
3   b   b2
```

I tried `df['val_shift']  = df.groupby('idx').val.shift(1)`

```
   idx  val val_shift
0   a   a1  NaN
1   a   a2  a1
2   b   b1  NaN
3   b   b2  b1
```

But I want.

```
   idx  val
0   a   NaN
1   a   a1
2   a   a2
3   b   NaN
4   b   b1
5   b   b2
```

Are there any way to get this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you need [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) last rows extracted by [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) with change index values for correct ordering first, because `shift` always remove last value here:

```
df1 = df.drop_duplicates('idx', keep='last')
df1.index +=  .5

df = pd.concat([df, df1]).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Alternative solution:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates('idx', keep='last').append(df).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)

df['val_shift']  = df.groupby('idx').val.shift(1)
print (df)
  idx val val_shift
0   a  a1       NaN
1   a  a2        a1
2   a  a2        a2
3   b  b1       NaN
4   b  b2        b1
5   b  b2        b2
```

If want remove `val` after `shift` use [`pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) with syntactic sugar - grouping by Series `df['idx']`:

```
df['val_shift']  = df.pop('val').groupby(df['idx']).shift(1)
print (df)
  idx val_shift
0   a       NaN
1   a        a1
2   a        a2
3   b       NaN
4   b        b1
5   b        b2
```

Comment: Thank for the good answer but I have some question. Does the last way give the fastest result? I can't test it with `%timeit`.

Comment: @yolox - tested too, you are right so necessary testing functions, give me some time.

Comment: Tested, second solution is faster.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

It looks to me like you're just shoving an empty dataframe infront of each group where only `'idx'` is populated.

```
pd.concat([
    d[['idx']].head(1).append(d)
    for _, d in df.groupby('idx')
], ignore_index=True)    

  idx  val
0   a  NaN
1   a   a1
2   a   a2
3   b  NaN
4   b   b1
5   b   b2
```

Alternative

```
df[['idx']].drop_duplicates('idx').append(df).sort_values('idx').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `concat` with `tail`

```
newdf=pd.concat([df,df.groupby('idx').tail(1)])
newdf=newdf.assign(val=newdf.groupby('idx').shift()).sort_index()
newdf
Out[885]: 
  idx  val
0   a  NaN
1   a   a1
1   a   a2
2   b  NaN
3   b   b1
3   b   b2
```